# Exercício de bolão em python

Tags: python

A dúvida é a seguinte, existe alguma maneira de fazer esse programa determinando a porcentagem que cada um vai ganhar de acordo com quanto apostou? e também como saber quem foi o maior apostador, do meio e o menor sem pré determinar isso.

> **Exercício:**
>   Três amigos jogaram na loteria. Caso eles ganhem, o prêmio deve ser
>   repartido proporcionalmente ao valor que cada um deu para a realização
>   da aposta.Faça um programa que leia quanto cada apostador investiu, o
>   valor do prêmio, e imprima quanto cada um ganharia do prêmio com base
>   no valor investido.

```
print('***O PROGRAMA IRÁ LER O VALOR DO PRÊMIO DE LOTERIA E O VALOR INVESTIDO PELOS 3 APOSTADORES***\n')

print('Digite o valor da aposta do maior apostador para o menor.\n')

p = float(input('Qual o valor do prêmio?'))
a = float(input('Quanto investiu o apostador A(maior aposta)?'))
b = float(input('Quanto investiu o apostador B?(aposta do meio)'))
c = float(input('Quanto investiu o apostador C?(menor aposta)'))

res_a = 0.5 * p
res_b = 0.35 * p
res_c = 0.15 * p

print(f'Proporcionalmente alinhado com o valor apostado o apostador A ganhou R${int(res_a)} reais.')
print(f'Proporcionalmente alinhado com o valor apostado o apostador B ganhou R${int(res_b)} reais.')
print(f'Proporcionalmente alinhado com o valor apostado o apostador C ganhou R${int(res_c)} reais.')
```

Comment: Sim, você consegue ler esses valores usando a mesma função `input` que já utilizou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde Yancruz32,

Para que você calcule a porcentagem de cada apostador basta você somar todas as apostas e dividir a aposta de cada pessoa pelo valor total, assim você obtêm a porcentagem de participação por aposta. Com essa porcentagem basta multiplicar pelo prêmio e você terá o valor que ele deverá receber. para saber quem foi o maior apostador basta utilizar o `if`.

```
p = float(input('Qual o valor do prêmio?'))
a = float(input('Quanto investiu o apostador A(maior aposta)?'))
b = float(input('Quanto investiu o apostador B?(aposta do meio)'))
c = float(input('Quanto investiu o apostador C?(menor aposta)'))

total = a + b + c
res_a = (a / total) * p
res_b = (b / total) * p
res_c = (n / total) * p

if a > b and a > c:
   maior_aposta = a
```

Comment: Obrigado pela solução cara! ajudou muito!

Answer (score 0):

Olá. Segue mais uma soluçao:

```
    #Ratear apostas de loteria
    pessoas = int(input('Quantas pessoas fazem parte do bolao:?'))
    contador = 0
    premio = 0
    dict1= {}
    for i in range(pessoas):
        chave = (input('Qual o nome do jogador %d ' % (i)))
        valor = float(input('Qual valor jogado pelo jogador %s ' % (chave)))
        dict1 [chave] = valor
    print(dict1)
    total = sum(dict1.values())
    total = float(total)
    print('O valor total jogado foi de  %s' %(total))
    print('A maior aposta foi %s' %(dict1[max(dict1, key=dict1.get)]))
    print('A menor aposta foi %s' %(dict1[min(dict1, key=dict1.get)]))
    print('A aposta media foi de %s' %float(total/pessoas))
    premio = float(input('Qual o valor do premio? %d' % (premio)))
    for chave, valor in dict1.items() :
       #print ('O jogador %s vai receber %d' % (chave, ((valor/total)*premio)))
       print(f"Jogador {chave}: Vai Receber R$ {((valor/total)*premio):0.02f}")
    print('fim de jogo')
```